# Antlr comment using alphabets

Tags: antlr

I want to ignore the line

```
CHECKSUM="some string".
```

I tried

```
CHECK_COMMENT
    : 'CHECKSUM=' (options {greedy=false;}: .)*  {skip();}
    ;
```

But this is not working, although this works for special chars.

```
CHECK_COMMENT
    : '========' (options {greedy=false;}: .)*  {skip();}
    ;
```

How can I make this ignored like a single line comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
CHECK_COMMENT
    : 'CHECKSUM=' ~('\r' | '\n')* {skip();}
    ;
```

where `~('\r' | '\n')*` matches zero or more chars other than line-break chars.

Or, including the line break:

```
CHECK_COMMENT
    : 'CHECKSUM=' ~('\r' | '\n')* LINE_BREAK {skip();}
    ;

fragment
LINE_BREAK
    : '\r'? '\n'
    | '\r'
    ;
```

Comment: This code is not working... shows "no viable alternative at input 'CHECKSUM'"

Comment: @Anoop, very hard to tell without seeing more. Please edit your original question and post the *complete* grammar and input that produces this "no viable alternative" error.